# Adding if statement in UpdateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to compare the user predictions to the actual scores of the matches. If the prediction turns out to be correct the column `result` will be updated to `true` in my prediction table. I'm using collection to loop through my matches and `updateOrCreate` to update my database fields.

**How can I properly add an if statement that checks if the values match with each other?**

**Code**

```
public function compareScores() {

    $matches = $this->getMatches();


    collect($matches['match'])
        ->each(function ($match, $key) {

            Prediction::updateOrCreate([
                'match_id' => $match['match_id'],
            ],[

                // if($match['homeScore'] == 'homeScore'  && $match['awayScore'] == 'awayScore') {
                //    'result' => true
                // }
            ]);

        });
}

public function getMatches() {

    $finished = Match::all()->where('status', 'FINISHED');

    return $finished;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried add home score and away score to paramters in the updateOrCreate?    like this:   `Prediction::updateOrCreate([
                'match_id' => $match['match_id'],
    'homeScore' => $match['homeScore'],
    'awayScore' => $match['awayScore']
            ]`

Comment: Marc - This would typically be a good solution, but he doesn't want to create a new Prediction if the values don't match. He just wants to update them.

Comment: Wouldn't the Prediction depend on the match_id AND the user_id? Right now you are showing code that suggests that there is only one prediction per match. Wouldn't you have many predictions per match?

Comment: I want to achieve that  every prediction from every user gets checked. So yes one match can have many predictions from different users. I don't think the user Id is relevant in this case because I check all my predictions not the prediction of a specific user only

Comment: I guess all I was asking is if there's more than one prediction per match. If so, then your updateOrCreate statement needs to have more uniquely identifying information than just match_id. If there are many predictions with the same match_id, they will all get updated each time you run this, regardless of which user made the prediction. And the final result will simply be the result of the last prediction that you check. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fully understand now. I would not recommend updateOrCreate for this case. I would do it this way:

```
public function compareScores() {

    $matches = $this->getMatches();


    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $predictions = Prediction::where('match_id',$match->id)->get();

        foreach($predictions as $prediction) {
            if($prediction->homeScore == $match->homeScore && $prediction->awayScore == $match->awayScore ) {
                $prediction->result=true;
                $prediction->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will run through each match and find all of the predictions that were made for it. It will then check to see if the prediction homeScore and awayScore match the actual score from the match. If both of the scores match, it will change the result to true.

Note that you could simplify this even further if you have your model relationships set up properly. Then you could eliminate the line where you pull in $predictions = Prediction::where('match_id,$match->id)->get(); Instead, you would just jump straight to the foreach loop and run this code:

```
foreach($match->predictions as $prediction) { 
    ...
}
```